# Is it possible to have multiple .PHONY targets in a GNU makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a big [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) command:

```
.PHONY: clean cleanall
```

Can I split it into multiple parts, as shown below?

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf build/

.PHONY: cleanall
```

Comment: Yes, a common pattern is to have a `PHONY` right above the relevant target. Can also have multi-line phonies by ending the continuing line with \

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, that's allowed. (If you don't believe me, just try it!)

Comment: And in fact you can do that for any target.  You can say `a: b` in one place and `a: c` in another and then the dependencies for `a` will be `b` and `c`.